# How do I fix my problem with executing code with OPENROWSET?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openrowset

I want to open an Excel dataset with openrowset function, but an error keeps on showing up:

```
begin
    declare @pathname NVARCHAR(max) 

    set @pathname = N'\\{DATAPATH}
    select @pathname

    begin 
        exec (' drop_table mytable
                select *
                into mytable
                from OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0; IMEX=1; HDR=YES; Database =' + @pathname + ';'',
                                ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'');

                select * 
                from mytable')
end
```

Which results in:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near 'end'.

Comment: why is `select @pathname` in part of your set statement? To answer your question, you have two `BEGIN` statements and one `END`. Each `BEGIN` must have an `END`. I'm not sure what you are doing with @pathname though. and that drop table statement.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Jędrzej_Adaszyński, welcome to stackoverflow! :)

you have to close a transaction, you have two and you have closed only one

```
begin
    declare @pathname NVARCHAR(max) 

    set @pathname = N'\\{DATAPATH}
    select @pathname

    begin 
        exec (' drop_table mytable
                select *
                into mytable
                from OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0; IMEX=1; HDR=YES; Database =' + @pathname + ';'',
                                ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'');

                select * 
                from mytable')
     end 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple different syntax issues to address.

The first is it looks like you forgot a quote at the end of your set statement, which then breaks the quoting of the rest of your script.

The second, as others have mentioned, is you have two begins, but only one end.

Try this:

```
begin
    declare @pathname NVARCHAR(max) 

    set @pathname = N'\\{DATAPATH}'
    select @pathname

    begin 
        exec (' drop_table mytable
                select *
                into mytable
                from OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0; IMEX=1; HDR=YES; Database =' + @pathname + ';'',
                                ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'');

                select * 
                from mytable')
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks, but it drops a bug again
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
    Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: What's the actual string built with your variable?